# How to Submit HTML Form from Using Complex Forms with JSoup

Tags: java, html, forms, jsoup, screen-scraping

Goal is to parse a HTML page from a site like Dice.com via Java JSoup and submit query text (like "Informatica") into that search form field.

I'm using Java JSoup but am open to other technologies, Java or otherwise.

Below is a snippet from Dice with sample of HTML form fields I'm trying to submit to.

I don't receive any HTML back from the System.out that shows that the search for "Informatica" was successfully posted to a form field.  How do you do a POST with a search, given the Dice form listed below?

```
 Connection.Response form = Jsoup.connect("https://www.dice.com").method(Connection.Method.GET).execute();

 Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.dice.com/jobs")
    .data("cookieexists", "false")
    .data("search-form", "Informatica")
    .data("q", "Informatica")
    .data("search-field-keyword", "Informatica")
    .cookies(form.cookies())
    .post();
    System.out.println(document);
```

Sample from Dice HTML source:

```
   <form class="search-form" action="/jobs" method="GET" id="search-form">
   <fieldset class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
   <div class="form-group">
   <strong class="title">Search across 77,990 Tech Jobs</strong>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-5">
   <div class="form-group">
   <div class="input-group">
   <div class="input-group-addon"><label for="search-field-keyword"   
   class="icon- magnifier"></label></div>
   <input type="search" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Job title    
   or keywords" id="search-field-keyword" name="q" autofocus autocomplete="off">
   </div>
   <div class="help-block">job title, skills, keywords or company name</div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
   <div class="form-group">
   <div class="input-group">
   <div class="input-group-addon"><label for="search-field-location" 
   class="icon-compass-3"></label></div>
   <input type="search" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Location" 
   id="search-field-location" name="l" autocomplete="off">
   </div>
   <div class="help-block">zip code, city or state</div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3">
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-8">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Find Tech    
   Jobs</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-4">
   <div class="text-right help-block link-as"><a href="/jobs
   /advancedSearch.html"><span class="icomoon-equalizer"></span> Advanced <span 
   class="txt-search">Search</span></a></div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </fieldset>
   </form>
```